# Recursively Generate all Combinations of given Subset Size (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, recursion, combinations

Observe the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void print_2d_vector(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    std::cout << "{";
    for(int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++)
    {
      std::cout << v[i][j];
      if(j != v[i].size() - 1)
      {
        std::cout << ", ";
      }
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
  }
}

template <typename T>
struct permcomb2
{
  std::vector<std::vector<T>> end_set;
  std::vector<T>* data;
  permcomb2(std::vector<T>& param) : data(&param) {}

  void helpfunc(std::vector<T>& seen, int depth)
  {
    if(depth == 0)
    {
      end_set.push_back(seen);
    }
    else
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < (*data).size(); i++)
      {
        seen.push_back((*data)[i]);
        helpfunc(seen, depth - 1);
        seen.pop_back();
      }
    }
  }
};

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> permtest(std::vector<T>& data, int subset_size)
{
  permcomb2<T> helpstruct(data);
  std::vector<T> empty {};
  helpstruct.helpfunc(empty, subset_size);
  return helpstruct.end_set;
}

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> flavors {"Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry"};
  auto a1 = permtest(flavors, 2);

  cout << "Return all combinations with repetition\n";
  print_2d_vector(a1);
  return 0;
}
```

Running this code results in the following output:

```
Return all combinations with repetition
{Vanilla, Vanilla}
{Vanilla, Chocolate}
{Vanilla, Strawberry}
{Chocolate, Vanilla}
{Chocolate, Chocolate}
{Chocolate, Strawberry}
{Strawberry, Vanilla}
{Strawberry, Chocolate}
{Strawberry, Strawberry}
```

Notice how this code does NOT do what it claims to do!  Instead of returning all combinations with repetition of a given subset size (the goal), it instead returns all *permutations* with repetition of a given subset size.  Of course, a way to obtain the combinations would be to generate all of the permutations as I have done, and then loop through to remove all but one of those which are permutations of each other.  But I'm confident that this is absolutely NOT the most efficient way to do this.

I've seen ways which use nested for loops to achieve this, but those assume that the subset size is known ahead of time.  I'm trying to generalize it for any subset size, hence why I'm trying to do it recursively.  The issue is that I'm not quite sure how I need to change my recursive "helpfunc" in order to generate all of the combinations in a way that's efficient.

Just to clarify, the expected output would be this:

```
Return all combinations with repetition
{Vanilla, Vanilla}
{Vanilla, Chocolate}
{Vanilla, Strawberry}
{Chocolate, Chocolate}
{Chocolate, Strawberry}
{Strawberry, Strawberry}
```

**So how can I change my code to obtain all combinations with repetition instead of the permutations in a way that's efficient?**

Comment: consider `for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) for( int j = i; j < 10; ++j ) { cout << i << ", " << j << endl;`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That would only work for `subset_size = 2`.

Comment: Does the output order matter ?

Comment: @JonDeaton: That's a correct observation. Do you think you can generalize it to work for other sizes?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think so... I'm working on a solution at the moment that I think would generalize. We'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the helpfunc loop starts from the index we are on and only considers the ones in front. The ones behind we don't want since they will only be duplicates.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void print_2d_vector(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "{";
        for(int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << v[i][j];
            if(j != v[i].size() - 1)
            {
                sizetd::cout << ", ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << "}\n";
    }
}

template <typename T>
struct permcomb2
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> end_set;
    std::vector<T>& data;
    permcomb2(std::vector<T>& param) : data(param) {}

    void helpfunc(std::vector<T>& seen, int depth, int current) // Add one more param for the starting depth of our recursive calls
    {
        if(depth == 0)
        {
            end_set.push_back(seen);
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = current; i < data.size(); i++) // Set the loop to start at given value
            {
                seen.push_back(data[i]);
                helpfunc(seen, depth - 1, i);
                seen.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> permtest(std::vector<T>& data, int subset_size)
{
    permcomb2<T> helpstruct(data);
    std::vector<T> empty {};
    helpstruct.helpfunc(empty, subset_size, 0); // Initialize the function at depth 0
    return helpstruct.end_set;
}

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> flavors {"Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry"};
    auto a1 = permtest(flavors, 2);

    cout << "Return all combinations with repetition\n";
    print_2d_vector(a1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think about solving this problem by having nested for loops, where each loop's counter goes from the previous index to the `data` size.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
  for (int j = i; j < data.size(); j++) {
    for (int k = j; k < data.size(); k++) {
      // etc...
  }
}
```

The trouble is that the depth of loop-nesting is equal to `subset_size`. We can simulate this arbitrary-depth nesting by having a recursive call in a loop:

```
template <class T>
void solution(std::vector<T>& data, std::vector<std::vector<T>>& sol, int subset_size, int start=0, int depth=0) {
  if (depth == subset_size) return;

  // Assume that the last element of sol is a base vector
  // on which to append the data elements after "start"
  std::vector<T> base = sol.back();

  // create (data.size() - start) number of vectors, each of which is the base vector (above)
  // plus each element of the data after the specified starting index
  for (int i = start; i < data.size(); ++i) {
    sol.back().push_back(data[i]);                   // Append i'th data element to base 
    solution(data, sol, subset_size, i, depth + 1);  // Recurse, extending the new base
    if (i < data.size() - 1) sol.push_back(base);    // Append another base for the next iteration
  }
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> permtest(std::vector<T>& data, int subset_size) {
  std::vector<std::vector<T>> solution_set;
  solution_set.push_back(std::vector<T>());
  solution(data, solution_set, subset_size);
  return solution_set;
}
```